# Выполнение внешнего файла

Tags: php, linux

Необходимо запустить процесс, использовал различные функции, типа exec(), system(), popen(), везде одно и то же: процесс отрабатывает именно столько времени, сколько отрабатывает и php скрипт, т.е. при запуске skype он висит в процессах секунды две и гаснет, при запуске из терминала все отлично...

Answer (score 2):

А что вы ожидали? Если нужно "отцепить" процесс от запускающего скрипта, то примерно так (упрощённо):

```
if( pcntl_fork() ) exit();
posix_setsid();
if( pcntl_fork() ) exit();
/*
    а здесь уже system('что_надо') и т.д.
*/
```

P.S. С огромной долей вероятности всё это a) не будет работать на многих хостингах, 2) если будет работать, то запущенная программа не будет работать вечно

Answer (score 1):

Google: php linux  выполнить внешний файл

первая же ссылка : [Блог Dead Krolik'а: Запуск внешнего приложения в PHP (exec ...](http://dead-krolik.info/2007/06/19/zapusk-vneshnego-prilozheniya-v-php-exec-system-popen-passthru-proc_open)

описывает 6 способов. Читайте, изучайте, выбирайте.

[@Артём Грибков](/users/6497/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2), IMHO в следующий раз за подобные вопросы Вас здесь неслабо заминусуют.

Comment: В том то и дело, что не один вечер убил на поиск решения данной проблемы, и вот от безысходности написал сюда. И, кстати, мне необходимо, чтобы внешний файл оставался работать после того, как закончит работу php скрипт, а по ссылке описываются способы отработки файлов и получения вывода.

Comment: Из запускаемого sh скрипта попробуйте 

    nohup comman-what-you-want &